# NSTask/NSPipe read from Unix command

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstask, nspipe

I am writing a Cocoa application which needs to execute a UNIX program and read its output, line by line, as they are produced. I set up a NSTask and NSPipe as such:

```
task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput:pipe];
//... later ...
[task setArguments:...];
[task setLaunchPath:@"..."];
[task launch];
handle = [[task fileHandleForReading] retain];
```

The command does not terminate until the program tells it to do so with `[task terminate]`. I have tried several methods of reading from the handle, such as `-readInBackgroundAndNotify`, `while([(data = [handle availableData]) length] > 0)`, and `-waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify`, but the pipe never seems to yield any data. Is there some way I can "poke" the `NSTask` or `NSPipe` to flush the data through?

**EDIT**: with `-readInBackgroundAndNotify`:

```
[handle readInBackgroundAndNotify];
notification_block_t handlerBlock =
    ^(NSNotification *notification) {
         NSData *data = [[notification userInfo]
                             objectForKey: NSFileHandleNotificationDataItem];
         /*... do stuff ...*/
         [self addNotification: handle block: handlerBlock];
     };
[self addNotification: handler block: handlerBlock];
//...
- (void)addNotification:(id)handle block:(notification_block_t)block {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         addObserverForName: NSFileHandleReadCompletionNotification
         object: handle
         queue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
         usingBlock: block];
}
```

with `-waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify`:

```
[handle waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];
notification_block_t handlerBlock =
    ^(NSNotification *notification) {
        NSData *data = [handle availableData];
        /*... do stuff ...*/
    };
[self addNotification: handler block: handlerBlock];
```

with `while` loop:

```
[self startProcessingThread: handle];
//...
- (void)startProcessingThread:(NSFileHandle *)handle {
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
         addOperation: [[[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
                             initWithTarget: self
                             selector: @selector(dataLoop:)
                             object: handle] autorelease]];
}
- (void)dataLoop:(NSFileHandle *)handle {
    NSData *data;
    while([(data = [handle availableData]) length] > 0) {
        /*... do stuff ...*/
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**: The arguments are set as follows (the command is `tshark`):

```
NSArray *cmd = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-R", @"http.request", 
                                         @"-Tfields", @"-Eseparator='|'", 
                                         @"-ehttp.host", @"-ehttp.request.method", 
                                         @"-ehttp.request.uri", nil];
cmd = [[cmd arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[self.ports map:^(id arg1, NSUInteger idx) {
           return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-d tcp.port==%d,http", [arg1 intValue]];
       }]] 
        arrayByAddingObject:[@"dst " stringByAppendingString:
            [self.hosts componentsJoinedByString:@" or dst "]]];
[self.tsharktask setArguments:cmd];
```

Comment: Post all your code (e.g. how you defined the NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification).

Comment: `typedef (^notification_block_t)(NSNotification *);`, of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a working example of how I usually do it:

```
    task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath:...];
    NSArray *arguments;
    arguments = ...;
    [task setArguments:arguments];

    NSPipe *outPipe;
    outPipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput:outPipe];

    outFile = [outPipe fileHandleForReading];
    [outFile waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(commandNotification:)
                                                 name:NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification 
                                               object:nil];    

    [task launch];


- (void)commandNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSData *data = nil;
    while ((data = [self.outFile availableData]) && [data length]){
        ...
    }   
}
```

Comment: This works well, but it reads the output from my command in 4096 byte blocks, which is less than optimal as I would like to have the data available as soon as `tshark` produces it.

Comment: Also I added `-map:` to `NSArray` as a category.

Comment: The arguments are ok. Try playing a bit with the methods you see under  Communicating Asynchronously paragraph of NSFileHandle documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html, replacing waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the async solution for getting the task output.

```
task.standardOutput = [NSPipe pipe];
[[task.standardOutput fileHandleForReading] setReadabilityHandler:^(NSFileHandle *file) {
NSData *data = [file availableData]; // this will read to EOF, so call only once
NSLog(@"Task output! %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

// if you're collecting the whole output of a task, you may store it on a property
//maybe you want to appenddata
//[weakself.taskOutput appendData:data];
}];
```

hope could help someone.