# How to Handle Command Line Prompt from a Cocoa App

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am successfully running a command with code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12310154/347339). It works just as advertised, only problem is that I am running a command that waits for user input in the command line. However, I want my Cocoa app to be able to enter the input to allow for the execution to continue. How do I go about doing this?

The command I am running is `ln -s -i <path 1> <path 2>` which displays the following prompt when `<path 2>` already exists: `replace <path 2>/<path 1>?`

Comment: Which command are you running, and what's the input?

Comment: Edited question to include requested information.

Comment: You need to use a pipe.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392271/nstask-nspipe-read-from-unix-command).